# Concatenate php variables and symbol to javascript function in php echo

Tags: javascript, php

I finally got the php variables to pass to the javascript function but they are passing as multiple and getting a warning.

Use of undefined constant app_name - assumed 'app_name'

How can i define the variables?

```
 echo('<li> <a href="#" onClick="runthis(\''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $row[activity]).'\',\''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $row[app_name]).'\');">');
```

Javascript

```
function runthis(activity) {
    alert(activity);
    //$('#live-area').load('../assets/php/multibox.php?id=' + activity);
}
```

I am trying to concat $row[activity] and $row[app_name] with /
my php explodes on / and breaks into variables

**UPDATE**

Here is what im doing with the data.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $app = $_GET['id'];
    $array2 = explode('/', $app);
    $activity = $array2[0];
    $app_name = $array2[1];
    $SQL1 .= "WHERE activity = '$activity' ";
}
```

I don't think im handling the string properly.

What should this look like?

I updated the echo onClick to this

```
echo ('<li> <a href="#" onClick="runthis(\'' . $row['activity'] . '/' . $row['app_name'] . '\')">');
```

It passes correctly to javascript but when $_GET loads it i get no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dumping PHP output into Javascript context.  Use json_encode() to do this properly:

```
echo '<li>..... ', json_encode($row['activity']), '</li>';
```

As it stands right now, your array keys aren't quoted, which'll probably cause PHP to issue various warnings, and those warnings will get output in your JS code, causing syntax errors.

json_encode() will take care of ALL the necessary quoting/escaping for you. It'll also be far more readable/maintainable than the abomination you've come up with.

---

comment followup, split onto 3 lines for a bit more legibility:

```
echo  '<li> <a href="#" onClick="runthis(';
echo json_encode("{$row['activity']}/{$row['app_name']}");
echo ')">';
```

Comment: I spoke to soon. This is still not working. Could you give me the complete line with your answer?

Comment: i updated the question with what im doing with the data to tie everything together

Comment: i tried the 3 line echo and get this error
SyntaxError: syntax error
runthis(

Comment: woops. had a `{{` in there on the second var. should be just `{`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting Use of undefined constant app_name - assumed 'app_name' because you're saying `$row[app_name]` instead of `$row['app_name']`.